# swipeable compatible with nuxt for a page like instagram reels

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I am professionally trying to make a page like reels page on Instagram for the social network project I developed. But for the video dragging part, I'm having a hard time finding nuxt compatible fast-running scrollable libraries. i found a few but they failed to run fast

I am looking for a library for the slide feature in instagram reels that is compatible with nuxt and works fast.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.